# CVS backup copy of latest repository version

Tags: cvs

I have a CVS repository and I've noticed that in my working directory (sandbox) there are files like: myFile.cpp.~1.3.~.  I thought that these files always corresponded to the latest one in the repository, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm wondering where these files come from and whether I can create them so that they are the latest version in the repository.

p.s.  i use emacs a lot.  perhaps that could be at play here too...

EDIT: I'm realizing that this is almost definitely something related to emacs.  It seems to know that I'm working on a CVS file and when I go to Tools->Compare Versions and compare the latest version it names the buffer almost identical to the format I descibed above (minus the "." before the last "~").

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like emacs. Emacs names temp files with a ~ at the end.

To turn that off you can add (setq make-backup-files nil) to .emacs

Comment: yeah, that is true, but this is different because the files have the version number at the end.  After tinkering more, I think this has something to do with Ediff.  Still, I don't know how the files were created.  There is some automatic feature at work that I can't figure out.